# Not able to create a iOS code sigining certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, code-signing-certificate

[image: Not able to create code signing certificate iOS]

Can someone tell why the option to create code signing certificate is disabled for my account

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just tested and it's not the holiday shutdown I suspected first. Do you have a paid account? Because testing on device is not possible for free developer accounts

Comment: I don't think that is it... I can get in there and get one right now!

Answer (score 1):

You have reached to the limit of maximum number of "Ad Hoc Distribution/Dev Certificates". To create new one you must revoke among old one.

Comment: I have only 2 Dev Certificates. Still it is not enabling the option to create a dev certificate... Any idea why??

Answer (score 0):

You have to have Admin privileges to create those type of certificates. If you are just a developer in that account and do not have admin privileges you can't do it.

Or... if you not a paid iOS Developer you cannot get AdHoc or Distributions certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all previously created profiles also remove them from keychain access then login into account option will enable